# IIS with two or more websites

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

Using windows 2008, I have a website in port 80 and another website on port 3128. When I surf on port 80 website, all works fine, but when I surf to port 3128 website, the only page that works is the default.asp. When try to follow a link (like test:3128/pages/login.asp) the ie goes to test/pages/login.asp and clears the port.

What do I have to do to resolve this issue?

Best regards

Ricardo

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your code is doing some redirecting or rewriting of some kind to a relative URL that doesn't include the port.